# Laravel - Leave count query not giving desired result

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel-5.8 to get the count of employees that have applied for leave and those that have not applied for a particular year.

I have these 3 tables: hr_employees, hr_departments and hr_leave_requests.

```php
class HrDepartment extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'hr_departments';
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'company_id',
        'dept_name',
    ];
}
```

```php
class HrEmployee extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'hr_employees';
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'company_id',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'department_id',
    ];
    public function department()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Hr\HrDepartment', 'department_id', 'id');
    }  
}
```

```php
class HrLeaveRequest extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'hr_leave_requests';
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'company_id',
        'leave_status',
        'employee_id',
    ];
    public function department()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Hr\HrDepartment', 'department_id', 'id');
    }  
}
```

An employee can apply for a leave several times in a year, but it will be counted as one. A department has many employees. Here is my code below:

```php
$leaveReports = DB::table('hr_departments AS d')
    ->leftJoin('hr_employees AS e', function ($join) use ($userCompany) {
        $join->on('d.id', '=', 'e.department_id')
             ->where('e.company_id', '=', $userCompany)
             ->where('e.hr_status', '=', '0');
    })
    ->join('hr_leave_requests AS lr', function ($join) use ($userCompany) {
        $join->on('e.id', '=', 'lr.employee_id')
             ->where('lr.company_id', '=', $userCompany)
             ->where('lr.leave_status', '!=', '0');
    })
    ->where('d.company_id', '=', $userCompany)
    ->select(
        'd.dept_name',
        DB::raw('COUNT("lr.id") as applied_count'),
    )
    ->groupby('lr.employee_id')
    ->get();
```

I want to display the result below:

[image: leave count]

I want to list all the departments, count the number of employees that have applied for leave and those that have not. if leave_status is not 0, then employee_id has applied for leave. To get applied in a department, subtract total applied in that department from total employee in that department.

If I have 3 departments and 50 employees. It shows all the departments and show the count those that have applied and those not not applied per department

However, instead of get the type of result in the diagram, it calculated all the employees as total applied.

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: you are showing Models but your query is not using any of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Option 1: Eloquent Relationships.

You could do it by using the `withCount` method. But for that you need to first define the relationships in your HrDepartment model.

```php
class HrDepartment extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'hr_departments';
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'company_id',
        'dept_name',
    ];
    public function employees()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\HrEmployee', 'department_id', 'id');
    }
    public function leave_requests()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\HrLeaveRequest', 'App\Models\HrEmployee', 'department_id', 'employee_id');
    }
}
```

```php
$departments = HrDepartment::select('hr_departments.dept_name')
    ->withCount([
        'leave_requests as total_applied' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('hr_leave_requests.leave_status', '=', 0);
        },
        'leave_requests as total_not_applied' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('hr_leave_requests.leave_status', '!=', 0);
        },
    ])
    ->where('hr_departments.company', '=', $userCompany)
    ->get();
```

## Option 2: Query Builder

You can get the same result by copying and pasting the query eloquent makes in the base query builder but it doesn't really look pretty in comparison.

```php
$departments = DB::table('hr_departments as d')
    ->select([
        'd.dept_name',
        'total_applied' => function ($query) {
            $query->from('hr_leave_requests as lr')
                  ->join('hr_employees as e', 'e.id', 'lr.employee_id')
                  ->selectRaw('count(*)')
                  ->whereColumn('d.id', 'e.department_id')
                  ->where('lr.leave_status', '=', 0);
        },
        'total_not_applied' => function ($query) {
            $query->from('hr_leave_requests as lr')
                  ->join('hr_employees as e', 'e.id', 'lr.employee_id')
                  ->selectRaw('count(*)')
                  ->whereColumn('d.id', 'e.department_id')
                  ->where('lr.leave_status', '!=', 0);
        }
    ])
    ->where('d.company', '=', $userCompany)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks. But hr_leave_requests is not related to hr_departments. I have hr{leave_request to hr_employees. and hr_employees to hr_departments

Comment: same principle applies. The relationship in the HrDepartment model just changes from HrDepartment hasMany HrLeaveRequest to HrDepartment hasManyThrough HrLeaveRequest. The eloquent code does not change but the query made is different so the query builder code looks a bit larger.  I've already edited the answer